# Advice on RF circuit design - Pseudo-Doppler

Tags: circuit-design, rf, antenna

I'm planning on building a Pseudo-Doppler Radio Direction finder, and have some questions for those more experienced than I am. For those unfamiliar, a Pseudo-Doppler DF device is a device that by sequentially sampling a number of antennas can, using the induced doppler effect, estimate the direction of an incoming signal.

While I have good experience with the mathematics surrounding the sampling theorems, aliasing and FFT, my experience with antenna design and RF electronics is very limited.

**My issue** is that between the 433 MHz antennas and multiplexor of type (e.g.) ADG904, a circuit handling filtering, amplification and signal matching with the ic must be made. I did note this negative answer regarding building a [433 MHz receiver](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31349/433-mhz-receiver) which was discouraging, since it is the only frequency I can legally use for testing. Note however, that I only need to pick up a signal, not extract any particular data.

**My question** is if there is any good literature or sources I can consult to get knowledgeable enough to create, for the purpose, a working circuit? My background is in engineering physics and I have some courses in analog and digital electronics. I would be okay reading a lot of material if that is necessary.

Comment: Any chance you may try to interest a teacher in an EE department? They may be able to use your skills to combine with a capstone project for their students, while at the same time providing you with the theoretical and practical details for implementation as well as access to the necessary equipment tools and their use-knowledge. You'd have to let go of the project timing, though. But it might be a win-win, otherwise. You will need access to some expensive tools and training in using them properly.

Comment: A DF system using switched antennas to produce a pseudo-Doppler shift is an advanced project for someone with limited experience in antennas and RF. Your receiver will have to detect phase modulation of the received signal, so it might be an analog superheterodyne design, or perhaps an SDR. You might get started reading this paper by an engineer who is also an amateur radio operator: https://telegrid.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/TELEGRID-IEEE-Presentation-DF.pdf

Comment: To clarify, the project does aim to use SDR. Hence demodulation and such will be taken care of using software.  The circuit is rather to breach the gap between the output of the antennas and the input of a multiplexor. For now, [this book](https://dl.icdst.org/pdfs/files3/788e5a657430d42fbd27392e88ce6bdb.pdf) by Chris Bowick caught by eye, a good starting point? Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consult the ADG904 data sheet:
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG904.pdf
or browse through IEEE publications:
[image]
or also consult the following old text:
[image]